# Page is blank when trying to access footer.html from a different directory level

Tags: go, goland

**Issue details**

I am using Go language

Page is blank when trying to access footer.html from a different directory level

**My folder structure is like below**

```
Go
   static
       css
           main.css
   templates
       front
           home
               home.html
           footer.html
   main.go
```

**main.go code**

```
func homeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/front/home/*.html"))
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "home.html", nil)
}
```

**html**

```
{{template "footer.html"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

See "[Go template name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41187671/6309)": a `template.Template` value may be (and usually is) a collection of *multiple*, associated templates.

Since `footer.html` is not in `home` folder, but directly in the `front` parent folder, you need to parse it too, for its name (`footer.html`) to be available.
This is illustrated for instance in "[How to Render multiple templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54658443/6309)".

```golang
func homeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/front/home/*.html"))
    templates = template.Must(templates.ParseGlob("templates/front/*.html"))
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "home.html", nil)
}
```

The second `ParseGlob()` is applied to the Template object `templates`, not the package name `template`.
I would choose a different name, like `websiteTemplates`, to avoid any confusion with the package name.

Then your HTML file should work

```html
{{template "footer.html"}}
```