# How do I use HTML templates in App Engine standard environment for Go?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'd like to write an Go App Engine app that responds to a request by rendering a template. Outside of App Engine, the code might look like this:

```
var templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/index.html"))

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data := ...
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", data)
    if err != nil {
        ...
    }
}
```

**What is the App Engine standard environment equivalent to the first line?**

In the example linked from the App Engine standard environment docs, the template is included inline: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-go/blob/part4-usingdatastore/hello.go#L56

In an example I found elsewhere for the flexible environment, there is a templates directory like I'm familiar with: https://github.com/golang/appengine/tree/master/demos/guestbook

Is there a way to have templates exist outside of source files in go in the standard environment? Alternatively, is including the template inline (regardless of size) always the suggested approach in the standard environment?

Comment: It works exactly the same way. I just have templates in a folder exactly like what you show. One verbatim is `templates/users.html`. What have you tried, and what errors are you getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go, AppEngine: How to structure templates for application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573644/go-appengine-how-to-structure-templates-for-application)